# Java - ArrayList in another method is empty

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm adding packets to ArrayList in PacketList Class from another classes.

```
public class PacketList {

    public ArrayList<PcapPacket> packets;

    public PacketList(){
        packets = new ArrayList<PcapPacket>();
    }

    public void addPacket(PcapPacket packet){
        packets.add(packet);
        System.out.printf("List size: %d\n", packets.size()); // Size is according to added objects into the list.
    }
```

Until now everything is working fine, but when I create another method to retrieve the list, it's empty..

```
public ArrayList getList(){
    System.out.printf("Size of list in PacketList: %d\n", packets.size()); // Size is 0
    return packets;
}
```

**Edit:** Sorry, it's actually whole code, only chopped..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacket;  

public class PacketList {

    public ArrayList<PcapPacket> packets;

    public PacketList(){
        packets = new ArrayList<PcapPacket>();
    }

    public void addPacket(PcapPacket packet){
        System.out.printf("Received packet .. caplen=%-4d\n", packet.getCaptureHeader().caplen());
        packets.add(packet);
        System.out.printf("List size: %d\n", packets.size()); // Size is according to added objects into the list.
    }

    public ArrayList getList(){
        System.out.printf("Size of list in PacketList: %d\n", packets.size()); // Size is 0
        return packets;
    }
}
```

Here I create PacketList

```
public class ThreadToSwitch implements Runnable {

    PacketList pl = new PacketList();

    public void run(){ 

// here I have just pcap init that i did not include, but the packet is ok

PcapPacketHandler<String> jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler<String>() {  

            public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {  

                if(packet != null)
                    pl.addPacket(packet);
            }  
        };
}
```

This is main where I call getList():

```
public class SwrMain extends Thread{  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        Thread tts = new Thread(new ThreadToSwitch());
        Thread ttr = new Thread(new ThreadToRouter());
        tts.start();
        ttr.start();

        ArrayList pList;
        int myint = -1;
        while(myint != 0){
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            myint = keyboard.nextInt();
            if(myint == 1){
                    System.out.printf("\nNumber of packets in list: %d\n", (new PacketList().getList().size()));

            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please post full code.

Comment: can you also post the main method or where you are creating the PacketList and adding packets to it?

Comment: I don't see where you're calling getList() in that code. Hint: if you add packets to a box, and then count the packets in another box, you'll get 0.

Comment: It doesn't matter because in method getList is the arrayList already empty.

Comment: @user3477891 if you know better, why ask? It does matter.

Comment: Sorry, I already added the code, I just thought the problem was in PacketList class.

Comment: So you create new instances of `PacketList` in a loop with `new PacketList().getList().size()` and then you wonder why each of them has an empty list?

Comment: @Tom Yes, I understand there is a problem with instances of PacketList. I'm trying to wrap my head around it right now .. but how is your question going to help resolve my problem??

Comment: I just don't understand why you're confused about a completely new list being empty before you add something to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, but you are probably calling `PacketList.getList()` from another thread than the one where you add packets. You might be running into some synchronization issue. If that's the case, try switching to a concurrent structure, probably a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).

Seeing your full code (including the code where you read the list) would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I dropped the whole class PacketList() and actually implemented CLQ. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

So your issue is that you are creating a new packetlist, then asking its size.  It is not the same packetlist that you create in the ThreadToSwitch method, but its own instance, created by the default constructor for PacketList when you call new PacketList

```
public class SwrMain extends Thread{  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        Thread tts = new Thread(new ThreadToSwitch());
        Thread ttr = new Thread(new ThreadToRouter());
        tts.start();
        ttr.start();

        ArrayList pList;
        int myint = -1;
        while(myint != 0){
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            myint = keyboard.nextInt();
            if(myint == 1){
                    System.out.printf("\nNumber of packets in list: %d\n", (new PacketList().getList().size()));

            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Think of it like this.  I have a dog named Fido.  I feed Fido until he is a really fat dog.  You also have a dog named Fido.  No matter how much I feed my Fido, your Fido doesn't get fat.  They are different, even though they are named the same thing.

Now, if I were to borrow your Fido for a while and feed him a lot, then your Fido would be fat.

Comment: If I understand correctly I have to create one instance of PacketList and add Objects to that instance and also return that one, when I want to access it elsewhere.